# How to tell if iCloud file has been downloaded?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, nsfilemanager

I have the following code. My goal is to decode the data once the file has been downloaded to the device. I used fileExists to check if the file existed on iCloud. And then startDownloadingUbiquitousItem to download it. But I can't figure out how to tell if it has been downloaded. May I ask if there is a way to tell its downloaded? Like a completion handler or notification?

```
            if paperyCloudURL != nil, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: paperyCloudURL!.path, isDirectory: nil) {
                try? FileManager.default.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: paperyCloudURL!)
                //TODO: Should have check if the file exist before load
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: paperyCloudURL!)
                dataModel = try! decoder.decode(DataModel.self, from: data)
            }
```

Comment: you need to set an observer notification. see here;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843828/how-to-get-data-from-a-file-in-icloud-after-reinstalling-the-app

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the file [`NSMetadataQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataquery) object key [`NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataubiquitousitemdownloadingstatuscurrent) is set to `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent`.